# How do you make a thread run it's contents, pause and repeat?

Tags: android, multithreading, loops, repeat

I've basically done this but my when I run the app, it runs the thread too many times too quickly before freezing. 
Looking to have my thread run through once, pause and then start the thread again.

I have tried:

```
                while (running.get()) {
        Thread threadstart = new Thread()
        {
        public void run(){

            try {

        Thread.sleep(integerTime);
```

and then had

```
 threadstart.start();
```

at the end. This is my exact code just with all the processes taken out.

All advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sleeping in the new thread - so your while loop will keep spawning new threads at a very fast rate, *each of which* will sleep.

Why not just create *one* thread which has the loop?

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        while (running.get()) {
            try {
               Thread.sleep(integerTime);
               // Do work
            }
        }
    }
};
thread.start();
```